# Adding interface to existing Object

Tags: java

I have a third party library which has a bunch of interfaces and builders to construct objects which implement the interfaces.  These constructed objects are then passed into containers.  I then have an interface in my application which I want to add an implementation of to an object returned from the builder.

Third party

```
interface ThirdParty1 { ... }
interface ThirdParty2 { ... }
class Builder {
  ...
  public ThirdParty1 build() { ... }
}
class ThirdPartyContainer {
  void append(ThirdParty1 toAdd) { ... }
  ThirdParty1 take() { ... }
}
```

My application

```
interface MyInterface { ... }
class MainBody {
  ThirdPartyContainer queue;

  MainBody() {
    ThirdParty1 foo = new Builder().build();
    // something to add implementation of MyInterface to foo 
    queue.append(foo);
  }

  void calledLater() {
    ThirdParty1 bar = queue.take();
    if (bar instanceof MyInterface) {
      // do something
    } else if (bar instanceof ThirdParty2) {
      // do something else
    }
  }
}
```

I know I could build a wrapper class that implemented ThirdParty1 and MyInterface and took an instance of ThirdParty which all calls where forwarded to.  However this means that if Builder.build returns something that is an implementation of ThirdParty1 and ThirdParty2 the ThirdParty2 implementation would be lost by the wrapper.

I expect what I am after is not possible, but being fairly new to Java and all the Magic that can be done I wasn't certain.

Comment: Not really, no. Java is not a dynamic language where such things would be possible and even recommended usage. There may be a more convenient solution than a wrapper, if you explain your use case further.

Comment: My work around uses a map indexed on the reference returned from the builder to objects that implement MyInterface, this works fine but I was hoping Java might permit a more elegant solution that would prevent the need to expose that map.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As what I want is not possible the work around are either making a wrapper:

```
class Wrapper implements ThirdParty1, MyInterface
{
  private ThirdParty1 original;
  Wrapper(ThirdParty1 original_) { original=original_; }
  // all implemented functions from ThirdParty call said method on original
}
```

This does mean that when passed back into the third party library the object can only be treated as a ThirdParty1 implementation, thus optimisations might not take place.  Its also a bit of a pain having to write all the forwarding code if ThirdParty1 had a lot of methods.

As such the alternative and method we had to take was mapping i.e.

```
class MainBody {
  Map<ThirdParty1, MyInterface> remapper;
  ThirdPartyContainer queue;
  MainBody() {
    ThirdParty1 foo = new Builder().build();
    remapper.push(foo, new MyInterface() { ... });
    queue.append(foo);
  }

  void calledLater() {
    ThirdParty1 bar = queue.take();
    MyInterface ours = remapper.get(bar);
    if (ours != null) {
      // do something
    } else if (bar instanceof ThirdParty2) {
      // do something else
    }
  }
}
```

The problem with this solution is that the map needs to be accessible to anything that's doing the lookup.  There is also the performance hit of looking up the map.

Answer (score 1):

Just implement your own builder which build instances of your `MyInterface` and pass that objects in queue.

Comment: That wouldn't work as the new objects would just implement MyInterface, not ThirdParty1 or ThirdParty2.  As mentioned in the original question a wrapper/forwarder class could be implemented but would only implement MyInterface and ThirdParty1, hiding ThirdParty2 or any other interfaces wich the returned object also implemented.

Comment: Obviously that `MyInterface` should extend `ThirdParty1` and `ThirdParty2`.

Comment: That would work if I had full knowledge of all the interfaces that the returned value where implementing, but as soon as that isn't known it fails to be a viable solution.